# Menu desplegable multinivel

Tags: html, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente Menu, y necesito que sea multinivel, despliega bien el primer nivel pero no el segundo

```html
<li class="treeview">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-envira"></i>
    <span> Región Brunca </span>
    <span class="pull-right-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                    </span>
  </a>

  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li class="treeview">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-institution"></i>
        <span>Fondos No Rembolsables</span>
        <span class="pull-right-container">
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </span>
      </a>
      <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <li class="active"><a href="programa_fondos.php"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Fondos </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

El que dice fondos No rembolsables deberia abrir el segundo nivel pero no hace nada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]